# Weak convergence of Binomial to Poisson - What to prove?

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution, convergence

Poisson's Theorem states that:

> For $X_{n}$ with distribution $\mu_{n}$ following the Binomial law $\mathcal{B}(n, \lambda / n)$ and $X$ with distribution $\mu$ following the Poisson law $\mathcal{P}(\lambda)$, it holds that $$ \mu_{n}(\{k\}) = \begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix} \left(\frac{\lambda}{n} \right)^{k}\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n} \right)^{n-k}= \frac{\lambda^{k}(1-\lambda/n)^{n}}{k!}\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\left( 1 - \frac{i}{n}\right)}{(1-\lambda /n)^{k}} \to \frac{\lambda ^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}= \mu(\{k\}) $$ for any $k = 0,1,\cdots , n$.
>
> Therefore, we have $\mu_{n} \Rightarrow \mu$ as $n \to \infty$ (where $\Rightarrow$ denotes weak convergence, or convergence in distribution).

I have been asked to prove that $\mu_{n} \Rightarrow \mu$ in this case; however, it seems as though there is nothing to prove, since we already have that $\mu_{n}(\{k\}) \to \mu(\{k\})$. Isn't this essentially the definition of what it means to converge in distribution? Or is there some subtlety here that I am missing?

Could somebody please explain to me what exactly it is that I am supposed to show here? Thanks.

Comment: Convergence in distribution is defined in terms of the CDF rather than the PMF, so I think all you are supposed to do is prove that the PMF-convergence implies the CDF convergence. See also Example 7.7 in these notes here: https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter7/7_2_4_convergence_in_distribution.php

Comment: @JeremiasK it seems like all that example is proving is that the PMFs converge, though. Also, by PMF, you mean probability density function, right? Just to be sure we're on the same page in terms of terminology?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. They refer to a Theorem 7.1, which I cannot find in the notes but which I think is the link that is missing (i.e., I suspect Thm 7.1 proves that convergence in PMF implies convergence in CDF and thus in probability -- which is really a one-liner that you can prove for yourself, too.)

Comment: @JeremiasK is it Scheffe's Theorem? Look here: http://www.statisticshowto.com/convergence-of-random-variables/ in Section 2: Convergence in Distribution.

Comment: @JeremiasK, Theorem 7.1 is literally right before that example. If you want to see the proof, you have to click on "proof".

Comment: I didn't know it had a name, but that Theorem you linked is the right one.